# Html.TextAreaFor inserts a line break in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

The page's model has a string property called instructions which is displayed in a textarea, and whether adding or editing the object, a line break is inserted for no reason that I can find.

Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Instructions) is the only relevant code. In Chrome and Firefox a line break appears in the text area, but not in internet explorer.

I'm at quite a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around some more I found out that this has to do with the AntiXssLibrary.

There's more information here
http://forums.asp.net/t/1693760.aspx/1

From reading this, it sounds like it's been fixed in MVC 4
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8848

If you're using the AntiXssLibrary and MVC3 you'll have to manually strip the line breaks with javascript.